# Who all is the Great Cock sending on this Epic Quest?

Tags: the-magicians

In *The Magicians* (the TV show, not the book) season 3 opener, "The Tales of the Seven Keys", Eliot meets the Great Cock (yes, yes, we know), who instead of granting him a wish — because, as the cock says, when has a granted wish ever *not* screwed over the wisher? — sends him on an Epic Quest. Well, not just him: the cock lists a whole bunch of other people, too. Except he lists them by attribute, not name, and I don't think I got all the references.

> "The one-eyed conqueror, the traveler, the warrior, the fool, the god-touched, the lover of tomatoes, and the torture artist... You have a brother of the heart with the foppy hair."

Does anyone have a list of what the cock says and who all is being referred to?

<sub>(Trying to search for an answer to this is complicated by the fact that this episode also has that epic pop-culture conversation between Eliot and Margo, but I'm giving up on getting *those* references before I even start: I read the subtitles and that'll be enough for me.)</sub>

Comment: [The Great Cock](https://media2.giphy.com/media/ZqlvCTNHpqrio/giphy.gif).

Comment: This bit? *"The one-eyed conqueror, the traveler, the warrior, the fool, the god-touched, the lover of tomatoes, and the torture artist... You have a brother of the heart with the foppy hair."*

Comment: @Valorum: yep, that's the list.

Comment: I don't think 'you have a brother of the heart with the foppy hair.' is part of the list, it's just an aside. So we've got: The one-eyed conqueror = Margo, The traveler = Penny, The god-touched = Julia. Four titles left: The warrior, The fool, The lover of tomatoes, The torture artist, and four of the main cast: Alice, Quentin, Kady, Eliot. My guess is Alice is the warrior, Quentin is the fool. Is it torture or tortured? If it's the latter, then I'd say that's Eliot, which leaves Kady as the lover of tomatoes which doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: This AV club article excludes Eliot from the list of possible characters, as well as possible Alice:

https://www.avclub.com/the-magicians-prepares-for-a-big-quest-with-bunnies-ki-1821975215

We've got Poppy as somebody who is part of the quest, and maybe Josh is lover of tomatoes? Kady could be the warrior, then.

Comment: @derivative, Josh is definitely the lover of tomatoes. I think. My biggest problem is that I don't know which one refers to Quentin, even though one would think he'd be obvious.

Comment: Also, given what we learn in a later episode, it sounds like the torture artist is Alice. Maybe.

Comment: @Martha is there a specific reference I'm missing with the tomatoes? I can't recall anything in the books or show.

Comment: @derivative, in the episode with Bacchus, Josh mentions that he misses being able to grow tomatoes, or something like that.

Comment: For someone who does not know *The Magicians* and its characters, this question is really amusing. But I rather stay in my ignorance than google for *that* character.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, here's a complete list with episodic justifications for the non self evident ones.

- The one-eyed conqueror: Margo, for, well, her one eye. Self evident.
- The traveler: Penny, because he is one. Self evident.
- The warrior: Kady because she fights The Beast during his first Brakebills appearance in S1 and also her education of the group in S1E11 *Remedial Battle Magic*.
- The fool: Quentin, from S1E13 *Have You Brought Me Little Cakes*, where Jane's caught in a snare and Quentin / Julia wait for the appearance of The Witch and The fool. To quote Quentin: "The witch and the fool, iconic. ... Ohhh.. Which one do you think I am?"
- The god-touched: Julia, it's explicitly stated that she is god touched by several characters, most recently the Faerie Queen in S3E10 *The Art of the Deal*.
- The lover of tomatoes: Josh mentions that he misses being able to grow tomatoes, S3E01 *The Tales of the Seven Keys*. (Thanks @Martha !)
- The torture artist: Alice, because of her actions as a Niffin at the very least towards the Lamprey and likely towards all magical creatures, discussed in S3E03 *The Losses of Magic*.

Answer (score 1):

Eliot was assigned the quest, so he can't be his own friend or helper.

Margo is the Conqueror, Penny is the Traveler, Julia is the God-Touched, Quentin is the Fool, Josh is the Lover of Tomatoes, Kady is the Warrior, and Alice is the Torture Artist.
Remember, Kady taught them Battle Magic, and Alice tortured Lampreys to death to see them turn into pretty, pretty lights...

Comment: Can you add explanations of why the descriptions fit for all of them? I know that Margo, Penny, and Julia are obvious, but just for completeness sake? (And then maybe I'd understand why Quentin is the fool...)